# Trying to resolve deprecation error in Component

Tags: ember.js

In my component I am getting the following deprecation warning on the console:

```
DEPRECATION: Action handlers implemented directly on views are deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object ( action: `setVehicleModels` on <App.VehicleDetailsComponent>)
```

I believe it is because I am calling `@send 'setVehicleModels'` in the last method but I cannot figure out what needs to change. Can the `setVehicleComponent` be an action and have `.on("init")`?

```
App.VehicleDetailsComponent = Ember.Component.extend(
  setVehicleModels: (->
    model = @.get('model')
    store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
    store.find('automobile').then ((autos) =>
      @.set('autoModels', autos.filterBy('autoId', model.get('autoId')))
    )
    @.set('selectedModel', model)
  ).on('init')

  modelChanged: (->
    auto = @.get('selectedModel')
    @.set('model', auto)
    @.rerender()
  ).observes('selectedModel')

  updateAutoModels: (->
    @send 'setVehicleModels'
  ).observes("model")
)
```

Full stack:

```
DEPRECATION: Action handlers implemented directly on views are deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object ( action: `setVehicleModels` on <App.VehicleDetailsComponent>)
        at Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.deprecatedSend (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:43617:11)
        at Ember.ActionHandler.Ember.Mixin.create.send (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:39742:31)
        at null.updateAutoModels (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:82677:19)
        at sendEvent (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:23928:14)
        at notifyObservers (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:24314:5)
        at Object.propertyDidChange (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:24159:3)
        at set (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:24392:15)
        at Ember.Observable.Ember.Mixin.create.set (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:33621:5)
        at null.modelChanged (http://localhost:5000/assets/application.js:82673:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@.send` it expects the function to be in the `actions` hash, and if its not in the hash you will get that deprecation warning.

If you want to directly call a local function from within the component you can call it directly like `@.setVehicleModels()`